# Preventing cross-site request forgery in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

What are the best practices in CSRF-proofing a Liferay 5.2.3 based site? OWASP recommends (`http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern`) using the Synchronizer token pattern, but doing this manually seems to be tedious, especially sharing the token across multiple portlets.

A comprehensive portlet container should be equipped to deal with this, and a [bug report](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-8399) from the Liferay site also seems to suggest that it does. However, I couldn't find any further information on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tomcat 6 or later, you could use the Cross-Site Request Forgery Prevention filter,
implemented in class org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter. See Apache Tomcat docs.  Maybe, helps you.